# copy command in terminal into clipboard with just one step

Tags: clipboard, lxde

My DE is lxde in debian11.If you want to copy command in current terminal,you have to highlight text in the terminal window with mouse first ,then hit `Ctrl+Shift+C`, the command now can be copied into a clipboard buffer.

```
debian@debian:~$  tty
/dev/pts/1
debian@debian:~$  ls -al
```

Highlight `ls -al` in the current terminal window with mouse first ,then hit `Ctrl+Shift+C`, the command `ls -al` copied into a clipboard.Two steps!
Is there a just oen step(maybe more simple hotkey) to achieve my target?

Comment: My DE is lxde in debian11.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like https://robotjs.io/docs/ you could setup a macro which copies everything after the $ on the first line:

```js
const { keyTap } = require("robotjs");
for(i = 0; i >= 255; i++) keyTap('left'); //move to beginning of line
// keyTap('home'); might work instead
for(i = 0; i >= 255; i++) keyTap('right', ['shift']) //select entire line
// keyTap('end', ['shift']) might work instead
keyTap('c', ['control', 'shift']) //ctrl+shift+c
```

Install robot.js (and node.js), put that in a file (macro.js) then make a custom keyboard shortcut that runs the console command `node /path/to/macro.js`

you could increase the 255 to something larger to accommodate more characters but this might also slow it down if you copy smaller strings of text

Answer (score 0):

Try customizing your terminal to copy into a clipboard automatically when you highlight text. It is usually doing so by default in Putty terminal.

[image]

[image]

More hints on terminal customization can be found here: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211292/a-terminal-which-provides-select-to-copy-and-right-click-to-paste)